# Restrict multi login in CakePhp

Tags: cakephp, authentication, login-control

I have a mission to limit multi login on site(f.e. login from different computers under same username). My PM want to do this with saving session id. How I can do it? I have idea to save flag to database after login, and unmark it after unlogin.. but if browser suddenly or accidentally closed it cant be unmarked. Help me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to store a UUID, the users ID and a timestamp in your databse:

1. On login create a UUID for the current session of the user (`String::uuid();`) and Store the uuid in the users session and also in a cookie.
2. If the users already has an active session or a cookie, read the UUID from there.
3. A user is now "valid" if:

   - The user logs in and no database entry is present. The UUID doesn't matter.
   - The user logs in and the timestamp is "old" (define your own value... 15 minutes?). The UUID doesn't matter.
   - The users UUID and the user id matches the database entry and the timestamp is not "old".
4. A user is now "invalid" if there is a different UUID in the database and its timestamp is not "old".
5. If the user logs out by hand, remove the database entry. If the users just closes his browser he can either resume his session via his cookie or his session (application session, not the browser one) gets automatically invalidated after the timestamp gets "old".

Drawback: If a user wants to switch the computer / browser fast, he/she must use the logout function or else wait for your defined timeout. However, you could also implement a mechanism which logs out the current active user on a session-collision and closes all active processes or whatever you are doing in your application :).